# When running code I get an opencv cv2 error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, opencv

This is the code im trying to run that I found on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax6P93r32KU

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os

def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

faceNet.setInput(blob)
detections = faceNet.forward()
print(detections.shape)

faces = []
locs = []
preds = []

# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

    if confidence > 0.5:

        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

        (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
        (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

        face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
        face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
        face = img_to_array(face)
        face = preprocess_input(face)

        faces.append(face)
        locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

if len(faces) > 0:
    faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
    preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

return (locs, preds)

prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

while True:

    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        # unpack the bounding box and predictions
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)

    label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)

    cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

if key == ord("q"):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

This is what happens when I run the code

```
PS C:\Users\rainb> & C:/Users/rainb/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe 
c:/Users/Public/Desktop/Python_Work/Face-Mask-Detection-master/detect_mask_video.py
2021-03-15 22:36:04.855886: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not 
load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2021-03-15 22:36:04.866930: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart 
dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Public/Desktop/Python_Work/Face-Mask-Detection-master/detect_mask_video.py", line 77, in <module>
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "face_detector\deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'
```

The file location `C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1121:` does not exist, and I was wondering how to change that file location to something else, or find a different way to fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the module "opencv" and then reinstalling it? And have you tried to execute this code in a different python environment in VS Code? Please try to remove or delete the source folder (\lib\site-packages\) of the module "opencv", and then reinstall the module to avoid damage to related files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error in the file extension. May be file called deploy.proto.txt ?
And one moment yet, check the real path, where this file is storaged

Answer (score 0):

i also refer this same code...i also felt the same error..
datapath is not correct thats y...
if you run this in colab you might change the datapath
like this
prototxtPath ='/content/drive/MyDrive/MINIPROJECT/Face-Mask-Detection-master/face_detector/deploy.prototxt'- this is my datapath u correct just it with ur path

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.